# Is there way to auto resize percentage columns when column group is collapsed/expaned in NatTable

Tags: eclipse, nattable

I found ResizeColumnHideShowLayer class at nattable version 1.6.
(about https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521486)

That is work fine for normal column headers only.
But, if I collapse a column group, no adjust size to fit window. (no increasing column size)

How can I solve the problem?
Is there way to resize other columns to fit window automatically increase?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not because the ColumnGroupExpandCollapseLayer is taking care of hiding collapsed columns.

Comment: Thank your quick comment. But I have solved the issue using column hide/show mechanism. See my answer below. :-)

Comment: Thank your kindly answer. Could you give me hint how to override to support collapse/expand operation? I don't know the solution. Perhaps do I have to  mix with classical ColumnHideShowLayer? Do you have plan to add feature to NatTable later version?

Comment: You need to implement a ResizeColumnGroupExpandCollapseLayer that works similar as the ResizeColumnHideShowLayer. Maybe even by extending it and adding the necessary expand/collapse methods. At the moment I don't plan to add that support. Not sure what happens in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I found solution by myself!
It works fine very well. :-)
I was run based on NatTable v1.6 version.(downloaded yesterday)

I think this is a basic feature, so I hope this feature will be included in the next NatTable version.
In narrow tables, behavior that collapsing column group means that may be someone want to view other column data more widely.

## Overview (Problem screen and solved screen)

I explain using two application(before, after) screen shot.

**Refer to bottom image if you want understand my issue easily at once.**

#### Problem screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMllX.png)

#### Improved screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA7uL.png)

## Solution summary :

1. Add event listener to ColumnGroupExpandCollapseLayer.

         (HideColumnPositionsEvent, ShowColumnPositionsEvent)
2. Handle above events.

         Get column indices which is hidden by collapsed

         Execute MultiColumnHideCommand with the indices

## Layer structure of my test code

```
↑ ViewportLayer (top layer)
| SelectionLayer
| ColumnGroupExpandCollapseLayer
| ResizeColumnHideShowLayer
| ColumnGroupReorderLayer
| ColumnReorderLayer
| DataLayer (base layer)
```

## Implementation code is below:

```java
void method() {
    ...
    columnGroupExpandCollapseLayer.addLayerListener(new ILayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleLayerEvent(ILayerEvent event) {
            boolean doRedraw = false;
            
            //It works for HideColumnPositionsEvent and ShowColumnPositionsEvent 
            // triggered by ColumnGroupExpandCollapseCommandHandler
            if (event instanceof HideColumnPositionsEvent) {
                HideColumnPositionsEvent hideEvent = (HideColumnPositionsEvent)event;
                
                Collection<Range> columnPositionRanges = hideEvent.getColumnPositionRanges();
                Collection<Integer> convertIntegerCollection = convertIntegerCollection(columnPositionRanges);
                int[] positions = convertIntPrimitiveArray(convertIntegerCollection);
            
                //Execute command to hide columns that was hidden by collapsed column group.
                MultiColumnHideCommand multiColumnHideCommand = new MultiColumnHideCommand(resizeColumnHideShowLayer, positions);
                resizeColumnHideShowLayer.doCommand(multiColumnHideCommand);
                
                doRedraw = true;
                
            }else if (event instanceof ShowColumnPositionsEvent) {//called by  ColumnGroupCollapsedCollapseCommandHandler
                ShowColumnPositionsEvent showEvent = (ShowColumnPositionsEvent)event;
                Collection<Range> columnPositionRanges = showEvent.getColumnPositionRanges();
                Collection<Integer> positions  = convertIntegerCollection(columnPositionRanges);

                //Execute command to show columns that was hidden by expanded column group.
                MultiColumnShowCommand multiColumnShowCommand = new MultiColumnShowCommand(positions);
                resizeColumnHideShowLayer.doCommand(multiColumnShowCommand);
                
                //Set whether or not to redraw table
                doRedraw = true;
            }
            if (doRedraw) {
                natTable.redraw();
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * Merge position values within several Ranges to Integer collection
         */
        private Collection<Integer> convertIntegerCollection(Collection<Range> rangeCollection) {
            
            Iterator<Range> rangeIterator = rangeCollection.iterator();
            Set<Integer> mergedPositionSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
            while (rangeIterator.hasNext()) {
                Range range = rangeIterator.next();
                mergedPositionSet.addAll(range.getMembers());
            }
            return mergedPositionSet;
        }
        /**
         * Convert Integer wrapper object to primitive value
         */
        private int [] convertIntPrimitiveArray(Collection<Integer> integerCollection) {
            Integer [] integers = (Integer [])integerCollection.toArray(new Integer[integerCollection.size()]);
            int [] positionPrimitives = new int[integers.length];               
            for (int i = 0 ; i < integers.length ; i++) {
                positionPrimitives[i] = integers[i].intValue();
            }
            return positionPrimitives;
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, but this way it won't be added to NatTable. With your solution a combination with hide/show and expand/collapse will not work. For example, you hide some columns, then collapse a group, then trigger show all columns again. The expectation is that only the hidden columns get visible again, but not the collapsed ones. But your solution will also make the collapsed columns visible without changing the collapsed state. The solution is to create a new layer that extends the ResizeColumnHideShowLayer and handle the commands. Feel free to contribute.

Comment: BTW NatTable 1.6 is not released yet